# Wifi works only after suspend Ubuntu 16.04 dualboot on mac

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager, suspend, broadcom

I have Ububtu 16.04 in dualboot on my mid-2010 macbook pro.
The result of `sudo lshw -class network` for the wireless interface is:

```
 *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 01
   serial: f8:1e:df:f2:4d:03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.37 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:21 memory:d3200000-d3203fff
```

When I start the system, it doesn't find any WiFi even if the enable WiFi option is on and everything.
I have also tried

```
sudo service network-service restart
```

but it doesn't work. The only way to make the WiFi work is suspend and wake the computer. Is there a way to have the WiFi working straight away?